# Variable Length Arguments (*args) in Python3

Tags: python, arguments

I am fairly new to Python3. I have a question with Variable Length Arguments(*args). Based on my understanding the reason why we use the Variable Length Arguments list(or tuple) is that they are useful when you need a function that may have different numbers of arguments. A function like this

```
def main():
    x = ('meow', 'grrr', 'purr')
    kitten(*x)

def kitten(*args):
    if len(args):
        for s in args:
            print(s)
    else: print('Empty')

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

gives the same output as

```
def main():
    x = ('meow', 'grrr', 'purr')
    kitten(x)

def kitten(args):
    if len(args):
        for s in args:
            print(s)
    else: print('Empty')

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

output

```
meow
grrr
purr
```

I don't see the difference, and why is it better to use Variable Length Arguments(*args). Could someone please explain this to me?

And also, what does the asterisk really do?

```
x = ('meow', 'grrr', 'purr')
print (*x)
```

output

```
meow grrr purr
```

seems like, it just takes the variables inside the tuple out. And if I do

```
print (len(*x))
print (type(*x))
```

it will give me error

```
print (len(*x))
TypeError: len() takes exactly one argument (3 given)
```

```
print(type(*x))
TypeError: type.__new__() argument 2 must be tuple, not str
```

Comment: What do you expect `len('meow', 'grrr', 'purr')` to do? Why? Similarly for `len`. `*x` is **not an expression**; it is special syntax.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does \*\* (double star/asterisk) and \* (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

Comment: I don't understand how there is a question here. You ask, "I don't see the difference, and why is it better to use Variable Length Arguments", but you correctly observe: "they are useful when you need a function that may have different numbers of arguments". **That is the answer to the question**. The example looks pointless because you use `*` for both the call *and* the function declaration. But we also have the ability to use it on only one side.

Comment: As an aside: this is not really a 3.x question. Functions have supported `*args` and `**kwargs` arguments [since at least 2.0 and possibly before](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/function.html), and function calls have supported the corresponding syntax [since 2.2](https://docs.python.org/2.2/ref/calls.html). But even then - there is normally no reason to specify 3.x nowadays, because even Python 2.7 has been **officially unsupported for over two years**; it is approximately as obsolete as Windows 7.

Comment: Thank you so much, Karl @KarlKnechtel! The sentence of "len. *x is not an expression; it is special syntax." really made sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `*` is used before a `iterable` like `list` or `tuple`, it expands (unpack) the content of the `iterable`.
So, when you have:

```py
x = ('meow', 'grrr', 'purr')
print(*x)
```

your output is:

```py
meow grrr purr
```

Here, `x` is a `tuple`, which is `iterable`, so `*` expanded the content of `x` before printing them.

**BUT**

When, `*` is used infront of the `parameter` in a `function` or `method`, it allows us to pass variable number of
arguments.

In your example,

```py
def main():
x = ('meow', 'grrr', 'purr')
kitten(*x)

def kitten(*args):
```

you are expanding the values stored in `x` in line `kitten(*x)` before passing it to the function `kitten`.
And your function `kitten(*args)` is defined to accept variable number of arguments. Because of `*args`, you were able to pass
3 arguments to it, `meow` `grrr` `purr`.

In second example:

```py
def main():
    x = ('meow', 'grrr', 'purr')
    kitten(x)

def kitten(args):
```

You are passing only one argument to the function `kitten()`, which is `x`, and its type is `tuple`.

**Advantage of using `*args`**

If you choose to use `list` or `tuple` as in your example.

First, you need to create a `list` or `tuple`
before calling the `function`.

Second, if you use `list`, you have to be cautious of the fact
the `list` is mutable, so if the `list` is modified inside the function, changes can be seen outside of the function as well.

Example

```py
def main():
    x = [1, 2, 3]
    >>> print(x)
    >>> [1, 2, 3]

    f(x)
    >>> print(x)
    >>> [9, 2, 3]

def f(x):
    x[0] = 9

main()
```

But, if you use `*args`, you don't have to worry about any of this stuff.

In your case, you have used `tuple`, which is `immutable` so, you don't have to worry about the `mutable` issue.

Comment: Thank you so much. I love the idea of Unpacking. That helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an example like

```
def main():
    kitten(*('meow', 'grrr', 'purr'))

def kitten(*args):
    for i in args:
        print(i)
```

looks pointless, because `*` is being used on both sides of the equation, and the values are provided directly. (I made it even more clearly pointless by inlining `x`.)

However, we *do not have to* do those things. For example, let's try using `*` only on the definition side:

```
def main():
    kitten('meow', 'grrr', 'purr')

def kitten(*args):
    for i in args:
        print(i)
```

Now we don't have to match up a specific number of arguments for the call, and we don't have to create a sequence (tuple, list etc.) locally to wrap the strings up into a single argument.

Alternately, using `*` only on the calling side, and providing the values indirectly:

```
def noises():
    return ('meow', 'grrr', 'purr')

def main():
    kitten(*noises())

def kitten(a, b, c):
    print(f'I am a kitten and I like to {a} and {b} and {c}.')
```

Even though the called function's logic doesn't involve iteration, we can treat our arguments *as structured data* that could be computed somewhere else, stored in a variable etc. as long as they correctly match the call.

Comment: Thank you, @Karl. Now I can see why is so pointless to have   `kitten(*('meow', 'grrr', 'purr'))`  Also, the idea of taking out iteration is brilliant.